# ruby converting a string into float destroys the digit

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
input=File.open("lala.txt","r")
genes=[]

input.each_line{|li|

    keys=li.split("\t")
    length=keys.length
    puts(keys[length-2])
    puts(keys[length-2].to_f)

    if (keys[0]["-"].class==NilClass && keys[1]["-"].class==NilClass && (keys[length-2]).to_f>0.98)
    genes.push(keys[0])
    genes.push(keys[1])
    end

}
```

inputfile:

```
1053_at/RFC2    203696_s_at/RFC2    0.9031699692435061  
117_at/HSPA6    1553158_at/C3orf34  0.9079515773059148  
117_at/HSPA6    1553513_at/VNN3 0.9237382047518812  
117_at/HSPA6    1553723_at/GPR97    0.9367168572635286  
117_at/HSPA6    1557852_at/---  0.9177916032275163  
117_at/HSPA6    1558525_at/---  0.9229865774037962  
117_at/HSPA6    1562481_at/---  0.9109034368848434  
117_at/HSPA6    1569385_s_at/TET2   0.9187904542249753  
117_at/HSPA6    1569830_at/PTPRC    0.900051189462974   
117_at/HSPA6    1569955_at/---  0.9028606652628463  
117_at/HSPA6    201393_s_at/IGF2R   0.9090699277161238
```

My problem is following:
I want to compare the number in each row with >0.98.
 If I write it just `keys[length-2]>0.98`it shows me an error that I want to compare a String with a float. OK. Lets convert a String to Float then by doing this:  (keys[length-2]).to_f . In converted it BUT it destroys the number: I get 0.0

output:

```
0.9031699692435061
0.0
0.9079515773059148
0.0
0.9237382047518812
0.0
0.9367168572635286
0.0
0.9177916032275163
0.0
0.9229865774037962
0.0
0.9109034368848434
0.0
0.9187904542249753
0.0
0.900051189462974
0.0
0.9028606652628463
0.0
0.9090699277161238
0.0
0.9002336615360215
0.0
```

What is wrong then?(Ruby: linux 1.9.3)
Thanks in advance

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I do not understand you.Why you cannot reproduce?

Comment: It works for me, that is. Try it. `'0.9031699692435061'.to_f # => 0.9031699692435061`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it works for you because you do not do what I do there. I am reading a line and spliting it and then converting. You are just converting. Yours variant works for me as well but the code is not only converting, it is reading the line and etc. And there is some kind of a bug in ruby with it.

Comment: When I try to run your code, it fails with error. Maybe you're seeing output of not the version you think you have. Did you forget to save file in the editor before running the code?

Comment: Your example prints `1053_at/RFC2    203696_s_at/RFC 0.9031699692435061` and then `1053.0` and finally fails with an *undefined method* error. (ruby 1.9.3p362)

Comment: @Katja: the question was "why .to_f destroys the number?". The answer is: it does not. The bug is somewhere in your code. Try inserting more debug printing.

Comment: I checked it one more time, no I didnt forget the save the file. And I get exactly the output I have below. Though when I copy the input which I posted and run the code I get the same error. But with my original file I get no error.

Comment: My guess would be an invisible character of some sort after the tab but before the number. if you ouput keys.inspect you'll see those

Comment: @FrederickCheung oh my god. you are right I get this: "\u00000\u0000.\u00009\u00000\u00000\u00002\u00003\u00003\u00006\u00006\u00001\u00005\u00003\u00006\u00000\u00002\u00001\u00005\u0000"

Comment: "And there is some kind of a bug in ruby with it." Sigh. I seriously doubt that there is a problem with code as mainstream as `split` and `to_f` as those are used by millions of lines of code repeatedly around the planet. As a suggestion, be very careful to not say those words until you have conclusive proof, and then go over your proof multiple times.

Comment: Oh Ruby-Fans, I am so sorry for saying such an offensive thing=))

Comment: It's not a Ruby fan thing, it's a programming maturity thing. Any language that is 10+ years old and has even moderate use is very likely to be innocent when "There's a bug in a core piece of code!" is thrown about. Bugs in core code are  obscure and lurking in deep dark corners.

Answer (score 1):

judging by all the null bytes in there, what you've got is utf16 text that you are interpreting as utf8 or ascii. Assuming you are on ruby 1.9, you can get ruby to do the encoding by doing

```
File.open("lala.txt","rb:UTF-16:US-ASCII")
```

which will convert the text into the default internal encoding.

Comment: it shows me an error: in `initialize': ASCII incompatible encoding needs binmode (ArgumentError)
 from prepare_cluster_matrix.rb:34:in `open'
 from prepare_cluster_matrix.rb:34:in `<main>'

Comment: in `split': incompatible encoding regexp match (US-ASCII regexp with UTF-16 string) (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
and if I change to just slpit() I get the following output:
0.8466334062280807
"\x00\x30\x00\x2E\x00\x38\x00\x34\x00\x36\x00\x36\x00\x33\x00\x33\x00\x34\x00\x30\x00\x36\x00\x32\x00\x32\x00\x38\x00\x30\x00\x38\x00\x30\x00\x37\x00"

Comment: You can transcode into ascii if you're sure that's all that's there - see update

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got some weird whitespace issues.  I think if you split on `/\s+/` and just use `keys.last` you should be good:

```
input=File.open("lala.txt","r")
genes=[]

input.each_line{|li|
  keys=li.split(/\s+/)
  puts(keys.last)
  puts(keys.last.to_f)

  if (keys[0]["-"].class==NilClass && keys[1]["-"].class==NilClass && (keys.last).to_f>0.98)
    genes.push(keys[0])
    genes.push(keys[1])
  end
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code could be written more Ruby-like, and take advantage of a well-tested wheel:

```
require 'csv'

genes = []
CSV.foreach("lala.txt", :col_sep => "\t") do |row|

  puts row[-1]
  puts row[-1].to_f

  if (!row[0]["-"] && !row[1]["-"] && (row[-1].to_f > 0.98))
    genes << row[0]
    genes << row[1]
  end

end

puts genes
```

This is the output:

```
0.9031699692435061
0.9031699692435061
0.9079515773059148
0.9079515773059148
0.9237382047518812
0.9237382047518812
0.9367168572635286
0.9367168572635286
0.9177916032275163
0.9177916032275163
0.9229865774037962
0.9229865774037962
0.9109034368848434
0.9109034368848434
0.9187904542249753
0.9187904542249753
0.900051189462974
0.900051189462974
0.9028606652628463
0.9028606652628463
0.9090699277161238
0.9090699277161238
```

And `genes` is empty because no values in the last column are `> 0.98`.